# How to convert TB to bytes in C#

Tags: c#

I need to convert TB's or anything more than 80 GB to **bytes**. How would I do this in C#? Which data type I have to use?

```
int TBsize = 1;
longbytes TBtoBytes = 1024*1024*1024*1024*1;
```

Comment: you can also use `var` so the compiler decides about the type. `var TBtoBytes = ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) type and the L letter like this:

```
long TBtoBytes = 1024L*1024L*1024L*1024L;
```

The `L` here is used to tell the compiler that this is a `long`, not an `int`.

You can specify the terabyte value like this also:

```
long TBtoBytes = 1099511627776;
```

You don't need to use the `L` here.

Now you can calculate 80TB like this:

```
long eighty_terabytes = TBtoBytes * 80;
```